# Copying row data in WinForms DataGridView isn't working for date column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

What I'm trying to do is select a row in a datagridview and then copy the data in the selected row to the other rows (which already exist but don't have data in various columns) in the datagridview.  One of the columns is DateTime.  When the process completes, the text field (Bill of Lading #) copies just fine, but the DateTime field only yields "MM/dd/yyyy".

Here's what it looks like before the copy is initiated:
[image]

[image]

I've tried converting the value from the source row (in the image, the source row is the first row in the grid and the value is 4/15/2020) to a string, to a date, etc.  No matter, it only ever shows the format.

```
            _fireCellValueChanged = false;
            //iterate through the selected rows and copy the shipping date, bol and destination values
            //get the source copy row values
            DateTime shipDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvSOW.Rows[_checkedSourceRow].Cells[4].Value);
            //string shipDate = dgvSOW.Rows[_checkedSourceRow].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            string bol = dgvSOW.Rows[_checkedSourceRow].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            byte destination = Convert.ToByte(dgvSOW.Rows[_checkedSourceRow].Cells[5].Value);

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSOW.SelectedRows)
            {
                //bol
                DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[3];
                DataGridViewTextBoxCell bolCell = cell as DataGridViewTextBoxCell;
                bolCell.Value = bol;
                //shipping date
                cell = row.Cells[4];
                DataGridViewTextBoxCell shipDateCell = cell as DataGridViewTextBoxCell;
                // row.Cells[4].Value = rsi.ShippingDate.Value.ToString("d");
                shipDateCell.Value = dgvSOW.Rows[_checkedSourceRow].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                //destination / buying customer
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell destinationCell = cell as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
                destinationCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[5];
                cell.Value = destination;
            }
            _fireCellValueChanged = true;
            _unsavedChanges = true;
            btnSave.Enabled = true;
```

The 'Destination' column isn't working either, but I suspect that if I can solve the 'ship date' problem, a similar solution for the 'Destination' column would work.  Maybe.  Or not.  :-(

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [DataGridViewRow.Clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone).

Comment: The rows to be copied to already exist but don't have data in Bill of Lading #, Ship Date or Destination Columns.  I added an image to the original question to show what it looks like before the copy is initiated.

Comment: What is the source of the DGV?  If it is a DataTable the the index of the DGV row and table are the same.  Then copy the table data and the DGV will get updated from the changes to the table.

Comment: The link to the Clone() method is more related to the code sample you can find there. It's the same thing, since `Clone()` doesn't actually copy the data, it just creates a *compatible* object. You *objects* (the Rows) are already *compatible*. You just need to copy some values. As shown in the simple example. You don't need all those *manipulations*. Just set the Value.

Comment: @Jimi - this did the trick.  Thank you very much.  I tend to overcomplicate things and in this case, it really was as simple as just setting the value.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @jdweng: "index of the DGV row and table are the same." - Do not count on that being true. When you assign a DataTable to the DGV.DataSource, it uses the DataTable's DefaultView (a DataView) as the row source. The view could be sorted.  Also, you could have unaccepted deleted rows in the DataTable that are not included in the view. Use the DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem property (a DataRowView object) and retrieve its Row property (a DataRow).

Comment: You always want the rows of the table to match the rows of the DGV.  So if you sort, sort the table not the DGV.